# Difference between "has started" and "is started"

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

From http://www.fao.org/docrep/004/y2876e/y2876e0i.htm:

> Once bargaining **has started**, other intermediaries remain at a distance and wait for their turn to deal, should the first intermediary fail to obtain the fisherman's lot.

Why has the writer used perfect tense in the above sentence?

If I say it with simple tense, does it mean the same?

> Once bargaining **is started**, other intermediaries remain at a distance and wait for their turn to deal, should the first intermediary fail to obtain the fisherman's lot

If the writer just wants to say that when bargaining starts, other intermediaries remain at a distance, why he has used perfect tense?

If i Say "Once Match has cancelled other teams players remain at a distance". Is it correct then?

Comment: You are correct in understanding that **has started** and **is started** mean the same thing here. The main point is that _while the bargaining is in progress,_ the other intermediaries must wait. **Has started** makes that just a tiny bit clearer, for reasons that the answers below try to explain. (It's because the present perfect means "even though the action happened in the past, the result is still in effect".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Has started" is an active voice, present tense, perfect aspect construction.  Since there is no object in the clause, this uses the intransitive sense of "to start".  It means that there exists in the present tense some condition that the perfect action caused.

"Is started" is a passive voice, present tense, indefinite aspect construction.  Because of the passive voice, it does not make sense to call this a simple tense.  This uses the transitive sense of "to start".  It implies that bargaining is started by some agent.  The author would avoid this form if there is no specific action or signal that starts the bargaining.

The simple present-tense form is "starts".  It is an active voice, present tense, indefinite aspect construction.  Like the present perfect, it would use the intransitive sense of "to start" in this context.

The author could have chosen to use the simple form.  That some condition exists because the bargaining starts can be reasonably inferred.  The use of the perfect construction, however, makes that condition explicit.  With the simple form, the finished action may have a current effect.  With the present perfect form, the finished action certainly has a current effect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i say "Our Match has cancelled". is it correct?

Comment: Actually, **is started** is not passive, or at least it doesn't have to be understood that way. Here are some comparable non-passive constructions: "My leg is broken", "The bargaining is done", "Your sweater is torn".

Comment: @user4084 No, "Our match has cancelled" is not correct. This is correct: "Our match is cancelled." "Our match has cancelled" suggests that the match did the canceling. "Is cancelled" tells the state of the match without suggesting an agent. "Our match has been cancelled" is passive, indicating that someone cancelled the match.

Comment: Thanks Ben. If i Say "Once Match has cancelled other teams players remain at a distance". Is it correct then?

Comment: @BenKovitz, your example non-passives are all, in fact, passive.  Something broke the leg.  Something did (or finished) the bargaining.  Something tore the sweater.  The agents may be unknown or irrelevant, but their existence is still suggested by the existence of the active-voice equivalents.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan This is a common misunderstanding of the passive. These examples describe the present _state_ of the subject, not the action that put it into that state. The fact that you can say "My child is grown" as well as "My child grew" doesn't mean that the former is passive. No agent "grew" the child. In the active forms "My leg broke" and "Your sweater tore", the verb is intransitive, so it can't be made passive. What's confusing is that the same verbs can _also_ be be used transitively, and the transitive form can be expressed passively.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Because of that ambiguity, it can be difficult to clearly express the passive voice in these examples. For example, "My leg was broken at 8:00" might describe the state of the leg at 8:00, because the act of breaking the leg happened at 7:00, or it might mean that the act of breaking the leg happened at 8:00. It's ambiguous. The problem is that **be** can serve as a linking verb _and_ it can indicate the passive voice.

Comment: @user4084 No, that's still not correct. You have to say "Once the match is cancelled, the other teams remain at a distance" or "Once the match has been cancelled, the other teams remain at a distance." (However, "the match has cancelled" might be OK in some circumstances. It depends on the local customs for talking about matches. There's no general grammatical rule. Sorry this is so confusing!)

Comment: @BenKovitz  You were on the right path.  Example:  "I have two legs.  One leg is hurt.  One leg is unhurt."  "My leg is broken."  "Broken" is an adjective in the usual meaning of that sentence.  It came from the past participle of "to break".

Answer (score 1):

While both of those verbs **convey the same meaning** that the process of 'bargaining' is going on, I think using *'has'* ***stretches*** the time, though a bit.

I see the use of *'once'* which denotes some point of time. So, to comprise, *is started...* talks about right there, bargaining started. On the other hand, *has started...* talks about the process of bargaining just being started with a *little* stretch of time.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So "match has canceled due to rain" has same meaning as above. i.e . conveyaing Time stretches

Comment: If i Say "Once Match has cancelled other teams players remain at a distance". Is it correct then?

Comment: *match has been canceled/delayed..or whatever* --If the activity is recent and you are informing someone. I mean that's what we practice.

Answer (score 0):

Classes have started/classes have been started/classes are started. Correct usage with reasons n conceptual clarity is needed.

Comment: correct usage with reasons n conceptual clarity is needed.

Comment: Please use the Ask Question button to ask a new question. Please also include your own research and understanding of the problem.

Answer (score -4):

"is" is present continuous tense.

"has started" is past continuous tense.  So the writer telling, that the bargaining started already.

Comment: Actually, the term for **has started** is "present perfect". You are right, though, that it means that the bargaining started already, and is still in progress.

Comment: Also, present continuous would be **is starting**. I take **is started** as simple present tense, but this is the sort of thing linguists can debate about.

Comment: "is started" is passive simple present. Simple present would be "Once bargaining starts..."

Comment: @miltonaut This how those debates get started. :) See my comments on Gary Botnovcan's answer for why **is started** is not passive (in this context).

Comment: Ugh, yeah... I suppose "started" in this case would be a past participle adjective. English is so frustrating! *shakes fist*